# Still wondering how to get Express to ignore matching route

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have this verbatim:

```
router.get('/top_level_questions,', function (req, res) {
      res.json({success:true});
});


router.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
      res.json({success:true});
});
```

what's happening is that a request to

```
/top_level_questions
```

will match the `/:id` handler. What is the official way to prevent that from happening>

Comment: The router uses regex for its pattern matching. Use an online regex tool to create a regex that matches anything *but* 'top_level_questions': 

Here is a neat tool:

https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code:

```
router.get('/top_level_questions,', function (req, res) {
      res.json({success:true});
});
```

Should be:

```
router.get('/top_level_questions', function (req, res) {
      res.json({success:true});
});
```

Comment: that was actually it :) that extra comma! fml